# Reconcile different opinions on a topic at different SE sites?

Tags: discussion, moderation

How does one reconcile different opinions related to discussing restricted topics? Here, "restricted" is a label placed on a topic by an external or third party (and not Stack Exchange network).

For example this Meta discussion essentially states its not SE's place to enforce external restrictions: [Should moderators enforce NDAs for software vendors?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/should-moderators-enforce-ndas-for-software-vendors). However, this Apple Meta discussion states its not appropriate to ask about potentially NDA'd information: [Are iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite questions OK?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/are-ios-8-and-os-x-yosemite-questions-ok).

I think the answers are stating different positions for the same topic.

Which site wins when there's a contention on policy?

Comment: I don't think the Meta.Apple.SE post you link contradicts the MSE post.  The Apple.SE post just starts that questions on pre-release software are usually nothing more than speculation and that is why they are off-topic.  The only reference is the NDA is in the 2nd answer and that is just a single sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NDA question on Meta Stack Exchange was originally asked on Meta Stack Overflow—back before the [mso-mse-split](/questions/tagged/mso-mse-split). If it were asked today, it probably would have been asked on Meta Stack Overflow. So let’s just assume it was.

Then the NDA question on Meta Stack Overflow represents the consensus for Stack Overflow, and the NDA question on Meta Apple represents the consensus for Apple. Different policies apply to different sites. There is no problem with this.

Now, if the NDA decision on Meta Stack Exchange as being network-wide, even though its original intention was likely to be Stack Overflow-only, that might be problematic; it’d be as if Apple’s policy was a [nullification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullification_(U.S._Constitution)). But, as stated before, if we take into account the time when that question was asked, it was likely asking about Stack Overflow only, so no problem occurs.

Comment: Thanks icktoofay. Should the Meta SE question be closed as not relevant? Or perhaps moved to Meta SO? It seems to be confusing at best since it does not apply. There's no reason to look at it or cite it if it does not apply.

Comment: @jww: I believe the policy is that any *resolved* Stack Overflow-specific questions are to remain on Meta.SE. I don’t think it makes much sense either—besides to cut down on the work of spelunking through old questions, migrating as appropriate—but Our Stack Exchange Overlords Have Spoken.